# How do I control views separately and as whole at the same time

Tags: swiftui

So I've been faced with a problem I've never faced. In the picture below is a Parent view containing many views (the individual arabic blocks).

[image]

When the user gets the answer right then the block becomes gray and disabled. This is achieved by having the individual language block own the view and change that state. `@State private var isDisabled = false`

But eventually if the user answers every one then all the blocks will become gray. How do I then reset all of the individually owned views Bool state to true??

I can't make it that the parent view own the Bool because although that will reset all the views back to normal, when its time to disable individual views again, that will just disable them all and of course this is undesired.

Will post a working example if needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few (many?) different possible approaches to this, but here's one:

```
class StateManager : ObservableObject {
    @Published var states = Array(repeating: false, count: 6)
    
    func reset() {
        states = states.map { _ in
            false
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @ObservedObject var vm = StateManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Box(state: $vm.states[0])
            Box(state: $vm.states[1])
            Box(state: $vm.states[2])
            Box(state: $vm.states[3])
            Box(state: $vm.states[4])
            Box(state: $vm.states[5])
            
            Button(action: {
                vm.reset()
            }) {
                Text("Reset")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Box : View {
    @Binding var state : Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            state.toggle()
        }) {
            Text(state ? "Disabled" : "Enabled")
        }
        .disabled(state)
    }
}
```

I'm using one ObservedObject to keep track of all of the states. When an item is tapped, it sends its value at the correct index in the state array.

The reset button works by just changing all of the states back to `false`.

By keeping your state in one place (the ObservableObject), you have a lot more opportunity to mutate the state based on other items' states and not run into the problems that you were having, where the child view only knows its own state and doesn't have control over the others.

Also, by using the `Array` for the states, you avoid having to make a bunch of repetitive @State items. Note that the `Array` could contain something more complex than just a `Boolean` value, too -- it could be a whole struct of information about the state of that object.

**Update**:
Version where the ObservableObject gets passed around:

```
class StateManager : ObservableObject {
    @Published var states = Array(repeating: false, count: 6)
    
    func reset() {
        states = states.map { _ in
            false
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @ObservedObject var vm = StateManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Box(index: 0, stateManager: vm)
            Box(index: 1, stateManager: vm)
            Box(index: 2, stateManager: vm)
            Box(index: 3, stateManager: vm)
            Box(index: 4, stateManager: vm)
            Box(index: 5, stateManager: vm)
            
            Button(action: {
                vm.reset()
            }) {
                Text("Reset")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Box : View {
    var index : Int
    @ObservedObject var stateManager : StateManager
    
    var state : Bool {
        stateManager.states[index]
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            stateManager.states[index].toggle()
        }) {
            Text(state ? "Disabled" : "Enabled")
        }
        .disabled(state)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Although I'm a bit confused by the syntax in the function

Comment: its a function, but right after the body starts there is a Binding<Bool> that starts a closure, what am I looking at here

Comment: Sure -- a Binding provides two-way communication between items. A custom binding lets you define certain actions to have when that variable is get or set (you can see a `get` and a `set` defined with closures there). I realized that in this case, it was a bit overkill, so I edited my answer to not have that there.

Comment: More reading on Bindings: https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/04/08/binding-in-swiftui/

Comment: I may have reacted too early because although this works it seems I can't apply this to views. The example you gave works for an object of a single view - an array. but how would I change the values of different views from a single view while still allowing the child view to set its own value.. its a bit awkward to describe. I guess the picture describes it better than I can explain it

Comment: Sorry, I guess I don't understand. I will say that you can pass references to the @ObservableObject around to any view through its parameters. In the mean time, I'd say try to explain more in depth and include code and where you're missing some functionality, because as far as I can tell, except for the layout and the pictures, I'm not seeing what's different between my example and yours. If you provide more detail, I can try to help you solve it.

Comment: In case it helps you conceptualize other options, I added a version where the state manager gets passed to the child views.

Comment: Thanks, I'm in the process of recreating some example code along with vids but I'll give that latest post a try first. Tomorrow though my brain hurts now 

Comment: So back at it on a fresh morning with a fresh mind. I implemented it and it worked, thanks so much. Although I am completely new to that style of 'State Management' .. is that redux?

Comment: It's not redux -- redux is generally a little more complex than this. But, it shares a very similar idea, which is that it can be a good practice to have one source of truth for your app's state -- eg one object or store that contains all of the state and possibly even the only ways to mutate that state.